# Statically Linked ELF 32 bit Binary - Distro Specific

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, binary

I've already determined that statically linked programs can't always run between different distros.

My question here, is if it is safe to distribute a statically linked program that is distro specific.

For example, I'd have an Ubuntu version of the binary, and a Redhat version of the binary and the user just downloads the correct version.

Comment: How exactly did you determine that?  Under most circumstances a correctly-written, statically-linked program should execute on most Linux distributions running on the same architecture, barring any major kernel version differences.

Comment: It sounds like "It'll probably work.. unless you have a strange distro... or upgrade your kernel"

BTW: This is how I determined it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605064/distributing-a-statically-linked-elf-32bit-binary-will-it-run-on-all-platforms

I was able to compile my program as a LSB binary but that then requires the user to have the lsb runtime installed which is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarifying answer, it seems reasonable to do that, although I'm not sure why it needs to be both statically-linked *and* distro-specific.  Almost all major distributions distribute distro-specific binary versions of packages (e.g. binary rpms or debs).  If you're going to go to the effort to distribute distro-specific pre-compiled binaries, why not distribute distro-specific packages that ensure that all dependencies are automatically satisfied?